# Is there any direct way of replacing suffix and prefix?

Tags: json, scala

In scala to remove prefix and suffix we have stripPrefix and stripSuffix . I was wondering if we have a direct way to replace this prefix and suffix with just 1 method call? For example I need to parse a JSON of this format:

```
[{
policy: "ha-all",
exclusive_consumer_tag: "",
messages_ready: 0,
messages_unacknowledged: 0,
messages: 0,
consumers: 0,
active_consumers: 0,
memory: 16011528,
slave_nodes: [
"rabbit@xxxx"
]
name: "W3_COMM_V2_BULK_EMAIL_H",
vhost: "/",
},

{
policy: "ha-all",
exclusive_consumer_tag: "",
messages_ready: 0,
messages_unacknowledged: 0,
messages: 0,
consumers: 0,
active_consumers: 0,
memory: 16011528,
slave_nodes: [
"rabbit@xxxx"
]
name: "W3_COMM_V2_BULK_EMAIL_ABC",
vhost: "/",
}]
```

For JSON parsing I need to remove the enclosing `[` and `]` which I can easily achieve with strip prefix and suffix but I also need to replace it with `{` and `}` and yeah I know there exist several ways to do this but I wanted to know the most direct and fastest. Or do I have to fall back on the regular `replace( specify regular expression )`?

Comment: Replacing `[..]` with `{...}` would render the string invalid JSON ... could you explain a bit more about the context of what you are trying to do?

Comment: The library i am using is not accepting a JSON starting with a " [ " ::::: org.specs.runner.SpecError: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{'

Comment: The actual solution then is to make it valid JSONObject - e. g. `{"data": your.array.here}`

Comment: I did parse it with some other library and I am getting this as an output of the parse : Some(List(Map(messages_ready -> 0.0,..etc))

Comment: How do I extract "name" from this directly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a regular expression like this,

```
val re = """(?s)\[(.*)\]""".r
```

where `(?s)` indicates matching on multiple lines. Thus for

```
val a = """[{ ... }]"""
```

extract the contents of interest for instance with

```
val re(x) = a
x = {...}
```

On the efficiency compared with string stripping methods, possibly the latter is a better choice, yet here once the regex is defined, a single call makes it.

For replacing the outer squared brackets, string interpolation may prove simple enough, namely for instance

```
val out = s"{$x}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions give great flexibility while dealing with Strings but if you know the format of it and you want to remove just `[{` `}]` characters you may just `subString()` it:

```
String s = fullJson.subString(2, fullJson.length() - 2);
```